# Error with Array

Tags: php, json, steam

Im not sure why, never used to use arrays anyway till now. Well, I have this code:

```
$inventoryJsonUrl = 'http://steamcommunity.com/inventory/'.$steamID.'/730/2?l=english&count=5000';
$inventoryJsonGet = file_get_contents($inventoryJsonUrl);
$inventories = json_decode($inventoryJsonGet, TRUE);

foreach($inventories['success']['rgInventory'] as $key => $description)
{
   echo $description['classid'];
}
```

And Im getting this error:

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

I have also another trouble, how to get name/value or whatever it is thatis market on this image (it is also the Json im using: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrHHm.png

If I can also ask, for any good but "simple" JSON tutorials for things that im using here?

Thanks for help.

Comment: `foreach($inventories['rgInventory'] as $key => $description)`

Comment: @Coder: `success` is just another key near `rgInventory`, not parent key.

Comment: Well, I just forgot about print_r($inventories); but thanks by that, I have done what I want to do. Thanks for help anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to do this:

```
foreach($inventories['rgInventory'] as $key => $description)
{
           echo $description['classid'];
}
```

Note: Steam API is a complicated API and often doesn't work the way you would like to. If you are calling more than 30 times per minute, make sure to use proxies.

Comment: Author wanted to do that. If we ignore the fact that ID is still added to the `value`, it may be helpful for an author to understand how it works.